# How do I use AlertifyJS dialogs in a browser extension (i.e. loading it in a JavaScript/TypeScript file rather than in HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alertify, alertifyjs

My browser extension has an onboarding page, and I've implemented AlertifyJS in the  tag of the HTML file as follows:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify.min.css"/>
    <script src="alertify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="onboarding.ts"></script>
</head>
```

No surprises here and this works fine. However, I now want to have Alertify dialogs not just on the onboarding page, but also on external websites on which the extension is activated. How do I get alertify.min.js and alertify.min.css into my content.ts script, such that it can bring up dialogs on any website?
Thanks in advance.